# Edit/Delete Button in Developer Story disappears after Edit then Save

Tags: bug, developer-story

In the *Developer Story* > *Story View*, each card initially has a gear button at the top right to show the Edit/Delete popup:

[image: before]

When I click on the gear button, then *Edit*, then *Save* it (it does not matter whether or not you made actual edits), the gear button disappears:

[image: after]

The `div` element for the gear button disappears from between the two `span`'s.

If after *Edit*, I press *Cancel* instead of *Save*, the gear button re-appears. But on *Save*, the only way to get that gear button back and make subsequent edits is to refresh the page.

I can reproduce it on:

- Chrome 74.0.3729.131
- Safari 12.0.3

Comment: Same thing is happening to me too, Firefox 66.0.3 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Same thing when creating new ones