# Bug - Unable to Edit Position on Developer Story (Story View)

Tags: bug, developer-story

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Go to developer story.
2. Click story view.
3. Click icon in top right on a position.
4. Select Edit from Dropdown
5. Click Save.
6. Notice icon in top right on the same position is not visible.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've reported that same issue here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/384431/2745495. It's been about 2 weeks, but no response/fix for that yet though.